# Mule OracleXADataSource and PoolXADataSourceImpl with UCP

Tags: mule, mule-studio

currently I have a flow in mule using a Oracle connection pool with UCP. Locally this flow is executed without incident.

```
<spring:beans>
<spring:bean id="oracleDataSource" name="Oracle_Configuration" class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolXADataSourceImpl">
        <spring:property name="URL" value="${oracle.jdbc.url}" />
        <spring:property name="user" value="${oracle.jdbc.user}" />
        <spring:property name="password" value="${oracle.jdbc.user}" />
        <spring:property name="connectionFactoryClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" />
        <spring:property name="connectionPoolName" value="connectionsPool" />
        <spring:property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <spring:property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <spring:property name="connectionWaitTimeout" value="10000" />
        <spring:property name="validateConnectionOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <spring:property name="connectionProperties">
            <spring:props merge="default">
                <spring:prop key="AutoCommit">true</spring:prop>
            </spring:props>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:bean>
```

I use the libraries ojdbc6.jar and ucp.jar with Oracle 11

When we perform the deploy in standalone,I have this error:

```
The method is disabled (java.sql.SQLException) oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler:488 (null)
java.sql.SQLException: The method is disabled (org.mule.module.db.sqlexecutor.connection.ConnectionCreationException)

Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLException: The method is disabled
at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:488)
at     oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:163)
at  oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolXADataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolXADataSourceImpl.java:108)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

thanking you for your support

Answer (score 0):

the connection properties "AutoCommit" is disabled may be.i am not sure. i tried with below datasource configuration it worked .

`<spring:bean id="oraDataSource" class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolXADataSourceImpl">
        <spring:property name="URL" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <spring:property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <spring:property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
        <spring:property name="connectionFactoryClassName"
            value="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" />
        <spring:property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
        <spring:property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
        <spring:property name="connectionWaitTimeout" value="300" />
    </spring:bean>`